# Missing style when rendering a angular material control

Tags: angular, angular-material

I’m using the angular rendering engine to render material components. But when I render the controls (in my case Cards => mat-card) they do not have any style. So everything that comes with the prebuilt-themes(node_modules\@angular\material\prebuilt-themes
).
[image: no style]

When I add a card by hand =>

```
<mat-card> test</mat-card>
```

And set the class Attribute at the rendering process it works =>

```
renderer.setAttribute(matCard , "class", "mat-card");
```

[image: with style]

So the Question is, how can I tell angular that it has to add the styles to the Page?

Here is the complete code I’m using to create the control

```
var matCard = renderer.createElement('mat-card');
renderer.setAttribute(matCard , "class", "mat-card");
const matCardInner = renderer.createText('Dynamic card!');          
renderer.appendChild(matCard, matCardInner);
const container = targetEl.nativeElement;
renderer.appendChild(container, matCard);
```

Thanks for your help
Michael

Comment: Why not simply use `*ngFor` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the [answer on Github](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/12453).

The solution was to pack the angular material components into own wrapper components in my project and then create the wrapper components. Then the styles are always available and I am able to add my own additional functions like validation in the components.

So for my Project I have now a component for each material design component I'm using.